# Opening a Realm file in Realm Browser that was created in a watchOS 2 extension

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, realm, watchos-2

I am using Realm in a watchOS 2 extension. Everything is working as expected but I cannot open the Watch Simulator `default.ream` file in the Realm Browser. When I try to open it while the Simulator is still running I get the following error:

> Realm file is currently open in another process which cannot share
>   access with this process. All processes sharing a single file must be
>   the same architecture. For sharing files between the Realm Browser and
>   an iOS Simulator, this means that you must use a 64-bit simulator.

When I try to open the realm file while the simulator is NOT running I get the following error:

> Invalid database

Has anyone successfully opened a realm file in Realm Browser that was created in a watchOS 2 extension?

**EDIT:**
I have updated to the latest version of Realm Browser (Version 0.95.2 (8)) and I am using these versions of Realm via CocoaPods:

```
pod 'Realm', '0.96.0-beta2'
pod 'RealmSwift', '0.96.0-beta2'
```

I have two Realm files. One is created in the iPhone App, the other in the watchOS 2 extension. When I run the app and the extension in the simulators I can open the iPhone Realm file without problems, but when I try to open the watch extension file, I now get this error message:

> 'default' could not be opened. It may be encrypted, or it isn't in a
>   compatible file format.

I have not set an encryption key in my Realm configuration.

Comment: With which version of the binding did you created the realm file on watchOS 2? Because the recently released beta uses a different file format, which is incompatible to previous versions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was not using the latest Realm Browser version. However after updating to the latest release I can open only the realm file that was created on the iPhone simulator, when I try to open the realm file that was created on the Watch simulator I am getting a different error message now. I've updated to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using one of the beta releases for 0.96.0, you will need to compile the browser yourself [from the beta branch](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/tree/0.96-beta).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for your help!